# CSS grids: align square cells with container edges with consistent grid gap?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The goal is to align square cells with their container's leading and trailing edges while achieving a consistent gap between cells on each row, and between each row.

This Codepen is close, but there are two problems: (1) vertical gaps are different from horizontal gaps; and (2) the squares are flush with the leading edge, but not the trailing edge.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wREmjo

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  width: 260px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
}

li {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="palette">
  <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(203, 58, 135);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(237, 106, 90);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(155, 193, 188);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(255, 247, 174);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(184, 51, 106);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(61, 44, 46);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(105, 173, 212);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(245, 223, 22);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(252, 186, 86);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 185, 252);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(181, 141, 182);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(58, 50, 96);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this not due to the hard-coding of widths? If you remove `width:40px` from the `li` options it's flush on both sides and the gaps are equal. If not, please clarify what the desired appearance is.

Comment: Check out this [article](https://medium.com/cloudaper/how-to-create-a-flexible-square-grid-with-css-grid-layout-ea48baf038f3) and its associated [pen](https://codepen.io/krystof-k/pen/vdNQGB), I'm pretty sure that's what you need

Comment: @Charlie how do you guarantee square shapes if you remove the width?

Comment: @Jake thanks will check them out!

Comment: @Crashalot oh yeah, good point. [Maybe this could help with that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the grid cells are fine but the content inside (`li`) is not matching them.

[image]

Instead of using fixed width/height on the `li` you can consider percentage value and they will be a bit bigger in some cases but will remain square elements:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  width: 260px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
  animation:change 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top:100%;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {width:120px}
}
```

```html
<ul class="palette">
  <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(203, 58, 135);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(237, 106, 90);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(155, 193, 188);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(255, 247, 174);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(184, 51, 106);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(61, 44, 46);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(105, 173, 212);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(245, 223, 22);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(252, 186, 86);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 185, 252);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(181, 141, 182);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(58, 50, 96);"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is the answer to your first problem no need to give width to li.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  width: 260px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(40px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background: gray;
}

li {
/*   width: 40px; */
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="palette">
  <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(203, 58, 135);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(237, 106, 90);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(155, 193, 188);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(255, 247, 174);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(184, 51, 106);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(61, 44, 46);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(105, 173, 212);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(245, 223, 22);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(252, 186, 86);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(0, 185, 252);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(181, 141, 182);"></li>
  <li style="background-color: rgb(58, 50, 96);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem of your solution is that the elements are no longer exact squares.