# css grid: possible to use a flexible number of rows and columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is there a way to use a css grid to create something similar to the iTunes cover layout

[image]

where each tile shrinks to a min-width when the screen size is decreased. If shrinking no longer is possible, there are fewer elements placed in each row, but each tile now starts at max-size.

As far as I can see, css grid usually requires to define either a fixed width or a fixed number of columns?

I have set up a twiddle to play around a little, however so far I was unsuccessful at specifying a flexible layout, which would add new rows and columns when needed: https://jsfiddle.net/dnu6g8wt/

```
<section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</section>

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div {
  min-width: 45px;
  max-width: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
```

I am not looking for a way that uses css grid, but sticking to css only would be preferred. The tiles being squares would be awesome, but I have no idea how one could create flexible titles with equal width and height using css only. I was able to create such a layout by using javascript in the past, however that gets complicated very quickly.

Comment: Yes! I just read this today: https://andy-bell.design/wrote/create-a-responsive-grid-layout-with-no-media-queries-using-css-grid/

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54928586/8620333 ?

Comment: or maybe like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54125439/8620333 ?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. Going to read through those. TIL: using the right query still makes a huge difference

Comment: maybe that could work(assuming you work with JSX):
style: {display: "grid", gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${colNum}, 1fr)`}